# how to change hotspot auto-off time using ADB command o Root?

Tags: adb, rooting, settings

Hi guys I'm looking for a solution on how to change the auto-off time of the hotspot with ADB command o Root, defatul is set to 5 minutes: "the hotspot will be turned off if no device will connect within 5 minutes" ... it's really stressful. .. does anyone know the command o root solutions? many thanks in advance...

PS: phone I have to use it only as a hotspot, I dont care about the battery or anything else, now its use is only as a hotspot...

specifications:
Model: Meizu M2 mini
O.S: Android 5.1 Lollipop
Root: at the moment I removed the root because I restored it to use it only as a hotspot, but I can ReRoot in 5 minutes without problems.
WiFi: good WiFi power, dual band 2.4 & 5Ghz.